# deparse(substitute()) within function using data.table as argument

Tags: r, data.table, substitution

If I want do deparse the argument of a function for an error or a warning, something strange is happening if the argument is converted to a data.table within the function:

```
e <- data.frame(x = 1:10)
### something strange is happening
foo <- function(u) {
  u <- data.table(u)
  warning(deparse(substitute(u)), " is not a data.table")
  u
}
foo(e)

##  foo(e)
##      x
##  1:  1
##  2:  2
##  3:  3
##  4:  4
##  5:  5
##  6:  6
##  7:  7
##  8:  8
##  9:  9
## 10: 10
## Warning message:
## In foo(e) :
##   structure(list(x = 1:10), .Names = "x", row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x10026568>) is not a data.table
```

If I deparse it before `data.table` everything works fine:

```
### ok
foo1 <- function(u) {
  nu <- deparse(substitute(u))
  u <- data.table(u)
  warning(nu, " is not a data.table")
  u
}
## foo1(e)
##      x
##  1:  1
##  2:  2
##  3:  3
##  4:  4
##  5:  5
##  6:  6
##  7:  7
##  8:  8
##  9:  9
## 10: 10
## Warning message:
## In foo1(e) : e is not a data.table
```

There is by the way no difference if `e` already *is* a `data.table` or not.
I found it on purpose, when I was profiling some code, where `deparse` was very time consuming because `e` was quite big.

What's happening here and how can I handle such functions for `data.frame` and `data.table` input?

nachti

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is because `substitute` behaves differently when you are dealing with a normal variable instead of a promise object.  A promise object is a formal argument and has a special slot that contains the expression that generated it.  In other words, a promise object is a variable in a function that is part of the argument list of that function.  When you use `substitute` on a promise object in a function, then it will retrieve the expression in the call to the function that was assigned to that formal argument. From `?substitute`:

> Substitution takes place by examining each component of the parse tree as follows: If it is not a bound symbol in env, it is unchanged. If **it is a promise object, i.e., a formal argument to a function** or explicitly created using delayedAssign(), **the expression slot of the promise replaces the symbol. If it is an ordinary variable, its value is substituted**, unless env is .GlobalEnv in which case the symbol is left unchanged.

In your case, you actually overwrite the original promise variable with a new one with:

```
u <- data.table(u)
```

at which point `u` becomes a normal variable that contains a data table.  When you `substitute` on `u` after this point, `substitute` just returns the data table, which `deparse` processes back to the R language that would generate it, which is why it is slow.

This also explains why your second example works.  You `substitute` while the variable is still a promise (i.e. before you overwrite `u`).  This is also the answer to your second question.  Either substitute before you overwrite your promise, or don't overwrite your promise.

For more details, see **[section 2.1.8](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Promise-objects)** of the R Language Definition (promises) which I excerpt here:

> Promise objects are part of R’s lazy evaluation mechanism. They contain three slots: a value, an expression, and an environment. When a function is called the arguments are matched and then each of the formal arguments is bound to a promise. The expression that was given for that formal argument and a pointer to the environment the function was called from are stored in the promise.

Comment: @nachti, does this not answer your question?

Comment: @[BrodieG](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2725969/brodieg): Thanks for the answer. As written above: How can I handle such functions for `data.frame` and `data.table` input? Should I copy it (needs a lot of space)? Or deparse everything first and then overwrite it?

Comment: @nachti, the latter, deparse first.  Also, if you want to avoid copies you should consider using `setDT` instead of `data.table`.  The former creates a data table by reference.

Comment: Perhaps use `delayedAssign("u", data.table(u))` in place of `u<-data.table(u)` in the first example?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid I don't think that helps; did you try it?  Desired output is likely `Warning: data.table(e) is not a data.table`.

Comment: You're right. I didn't test it. Thanks for checking! In my current tests, it deparses to `data.table(u)`, whereas I guess the questioner wants `data.table(e)` or simply `e`.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do this with `sprintf` too, along with `is.data.table`.

```
> e <- data.frame(x = 1:10)
> foo <- function(u){
      nu <- deparse(substitute(u))
      if(!is.data.table(u)){
          warning(sprintf('%s is not a data table', nu))
          u
      } else {
          u
      }
  }
> foo(e)
    x
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   6
7   7
8   8
9   9
10 10
Warning message:
In foo(e) : e is not a data table
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers! @Richard: Good idea, but then it's still NOT a data.table and I can't use `:=` for example. It should be used within a function, which accepts either a `data.frame` or a `data.table` as input, do something in `data.table` syntax and convert it back to a `data.frame` if the input was one. BTW `u` is big (~250 MB)